# Mac equivalent of arecord command?

Tags: macos, shell

I've been googling around for the past hour but haven't found anything reliable yet.

I am wondering if there is a mac equivalent of the `arecord` command that would work, for example, in the following example:

```
sox -t .wav "|arecord -d 2" -n stat
```

Answer (score 4):

You can natively use the utility afplay to play audio files from command line...

```
afplay sound.wav
```

You can use sox to record (avalable from [macports](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=sox) and probably from [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/))

```
sox -d recording.wav
```

Comment: What exactly is supposed to do you example?

Comment: @Alexadre output the stats from a two second microphone-inputted audio sample