# Control Quicktime Using Applescript

Tags: applescript, quicktime

I am looking for a solution to control Quicktime using Applescript.
All I need to do is - 
- open quicktime and start a recording
- stop the recording and save the file to a set location.

From previous posts I managed to get the following.

```
    set theFilePath to "/Users/jamestebb/Desktop/01TestRecords/ " & "myfile" & ".mov"

tell application "QuickTime Player"
    set newMovieRecording to new movie recording
    tell newMovieRecording
        start
        delay 5
        pause
        save newMovieRecording in POSIX file theFilePath
        stop
        close newMovieRecording
    end
```

This works perfectly however, for this project I need separate script cues to start and stop the recording as opposed to having a wait / delay.

To start the recording I used.

```
set theFilePath to "/Users/jamestebb/Desktop/01TestRecords/ " & "myfile" & ".mov"

tell application "QuickTime Player"
    set newMovieRecording to new movie recording
    tell newMovieRecording
        start

    end tell
end tell
```

This works fine however when I try to stop the recording using the below I get errors where Pause is not understood

```
set theFilePath to "/Users/jamestebb/Desktop/01TestRecords/ " & "myfile" & ".mov"

tell application "QuickTime Player"
    set MovieRecording to new movie recording
    tell MovieRecording

        pause
        save MovieRecording in POSIX file theFilePath
        stop
        close MovieRecording
    end tell
end tell
```

Im guessing that this is because the file currently recording is no longer a "new movie recording"

Any ideas soon how to fix??

Comment: Please have a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

I used the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* to test starting a **New Movie Recording** in **QuickTime Player** with the first *script*, and then processed it with a second *script* to *pause, save, stop* and *close* it.

- <sup>Note that this assumes **QuickTime Player** is running with just the one  **New Movie Recording** and no other **QuickTime Player** windows open.</sup>

**Script 1:**

```
tell application "QuickTime Player" to start (new movie recording)
```

---

**Script 2:**

```
set theFilePath to POSIX path of (path to movies folder) & "myMovie.mov"

tell application "QuickTime Player"
    tell document "Movie Recording"
        pause
        save it in POSIX file theFilePath
        stop
        close
    end tell
end tell
```

---

Between these two *scripts* it successfully created the **myMovie.mov** *file* in the **Movies** *folder* of my **Home** *folder*.

Testing was done under **macOS High Sierra**.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The script does not work for my older Macbook Air especially for longer recordings.

So, I learned about "sox".  (this is for audio recordings only). I use Applescript and integrate that with recording with Terminal. Abort the recording with Control + C.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "Terminal" to activate
    delay 1
    repeat 2 times
        delay 2
        key code 8 using {control down}
    end repeat
```

end tell

[Mac equivalent of arecord command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40375074/mac-equivalent-of-arecord-command)